# How to implement something like this GIF that using mouse drag and select items

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the feature I want but I don't know how to implement it or what word should i google, thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snpiZ.gif)

Comment: You could google "freelance web developer".

Comment: I never ask there before, but this time i really need to know what this feature's name or tell me how does it working and i can implement myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the closest you could get with the use of Selectable() provided by JQuery. I have provided a demonstration below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#selectable").selectable();
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#selectable .ui-selecting {
  background: #FECA40;
}

#selectable .ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

#selectable {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  display:inline;
}

#selectable img {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <div id = "selectable">
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/><img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <br>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/><img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <br>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/><img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <br>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/><img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    <img class = "ui-widget-content" src="https://image.flaticon.com/teams/slug/freepik.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: I had have try this before but it's not what i want.

Comment: @HarshitDamani i think your answer completely satisfies the demand

Comment: What? I had try jquery ui. OMG it's simple, I don't know what wrong with me LOL. It's what i want, thank you

Comment: @AnandSiddharth I think so too, that's the implementation of what had been provided in the question.

Comment: @HarshitDamani Actually i need implement it in React and you give me a nice example and idear, thanks again

Comment: @李彥欣 Oh ReactJS, well I hope it works out well for you and your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This library serves your purpose
https://thibaultjanbeyer.github.io/DragSelect/

Comment: I had implement something like this before but it's different with what i want